# Subtract the row values in single column taking first row value as base value to perform task in sql ssrs report builder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to subtract the row values from a column in SSRS report builder to calculate the per day cumulative hourly run hour having first row value as lifetime run hour till yesterday. Could anyone please help me how to proceed. Please refer the image for required report format.

```
DATE  TIME          RUNHR COLUMN A(RUN HR in MINUTES)                   ROW NO
12/12/2018 00:00AM  100    100(TOTAL RUN HR TILL YEST MID-NIGHT11:45PM)   1
12/12/2018 00:30AM  101    1  (I HAVE TO START SUBTRACTING FROM HERE)     2 
12/12/2018 01:00AM  105    5                                              3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

12/12/2018 11:00PM  130    30                                             47
12/12/2018 11:30PM  135    35                                             48
```

I want to display the value as shown in COLUMN A, where the first row in COLUMN A shows the total RUNHR from yesterday and subsequent rows (2 to 48) showing the cumulative (to that time) RUNHR for that day only (i.e. since the value in the first row).

Answer (score 0):

Given RUNHR is cumulative, you could do this by joining on the minimum value of RUNHR for that period (assuming your dataset is based in Sql):

```
SELECT PumpId, PumpName, SampleTime, RUNHR, StartingValue, (RUNHR - StartingValue) AS COLUMNA
FROM PumpDataTable A
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT PumpId, MIN(RUNHR) AS StartingValue 
  FROM PumpDataTable 
  WHERE SampleTime >= @StartTIme AND SampleTime <= @EndTime GROUP BY PumpId) B ON A.PumpId = B.PumpId
WHERE PumpId = @PumpId 
  AND SampleTime >= @StartTIme AND SampleTime <= @EndTime 
ORDER BY SampleTime
```